# Discard unsaved changes to view in D8

Tags: views

I made a bunch of changes to a D8 view and have not saved it yet. I decided I don't want to go through with these changes and I want to discard all unsaved changes. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Drupal 7 or Drupal 8?

Comment: Have you tried going 'Back to site'?

Comment: @AjayReddy D8. I updated the question to include version.

Comment: @Sheedo, yes. I tried that. Unfortunately, the changes are still persisted but not "saved."

Comment: Click Cancel instead of Save.

Comment: @Kevin OMG. Navigating away doesnt work but [Cancel] does. No wonder why googling the problem yielded no results. It was right in front of my face. Post it as an answer and ill mark it.

Comment: Click cancel button next to save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to click on the **Cancel** button nearby the **Save** button